# Error uploading images with the kosalgeek library

Tags: java, android

I tried to make uploading images with the kosalgeek library, but when I run this problem occurs. how to overcome the problem.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.chakam.kampunganggrek, PID: 12687
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2222, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:24 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.chakam.kampunganggrek/com.chakam.kampunganggrek.StatusActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:24"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:24"
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
        at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:808)
        at com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(RealPathUtil.java:38)
        at com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.GalleryPhoto.getPath(GalleryPhoto.java:49)
        at com.chakam.kampunganggrek.StatusActivity.onActivityResult(StatusActivity.java:238)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
        resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == TAG_GALLERY) {
            Uri uri_path = data.getData();
            mGalery.setPhotoUri(uri_path);
            String path = mGalery.getPath();
            selected_photo = path;
            try {
                //Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(path).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();                   gambar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Success Loader Image", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Something Wrong", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid in future to put extrnal links if you can just put the text of the exception

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the string `Uri uri_path = data.getData();`  set with `mGalery.setPhotoUri(uri_path)` and used in the `GalleryPhoto.getPath()` util method.

As you can see from the code published  in [the github repository of this library](https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil/blob/master/PhotoUtil/app/src/main/java/com/kosalgeek/android/photoutil/RealPathUtil.java) the `uri_path` you is passed to                `DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(photoUri)` to extract an Id  that is supposed to be a nunmber.
In your case is a String `msf:24`and a Numberformat exception is raised.

I guess you should check if the string you are passing as Uri in the event `data`   is in the correct format.